# Devise sign user out without their session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

How can I sign a user out without their session (i.e. they're not the `current_user`).

I've tried the `sign_out(user)` controller helper, but that seems to sign out the `current_user` regardless of the user it's passed.

I can't seem to find a relationship between the sessions table and the users table either.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking. You want their session to still be active but dont want them to be the `current_user`?

Comment: @Deekor basically we want to allow admins to log users out, so the user we want to log out isn't the current_user

Answer (score 0):

try `sign_out @user`

where @user is the user instance which admin wants to logout

Comment: That logs the current_user (the admin) out instead of logging the intended user out.